# Symfony2 deployment via ftp

Tags: windows, deployment, ftp, symfony

I tried to deploy my project with capifony, becouse I found here an answer, that with capifony deployment is easy. Well I don't think it is, so my question is: 
How can I deploy my project via ftp, I put all my files on the server but even if I browse to web/app.php, the only thing I get is an empty page, whatever route I write in the url. So someone please explain me how can I get this work! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of things to think of when deploying a Symfony2 project to a new server or computer (as far as I've encountered) might be:

- Make sure that the server and it's PHP installation meets the Symfony2 requirements (and perhaps also the recommendations)
- Check that you've somewhat followed the installation instructions ([found here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html))
- Try to clear the cache
- Make sure that the web server and it's PHP process have write permissions to the cache folder

If none of these helps, try to modify the app_dev.php to temporarily allow access from your current (client) IP (instead of restraining it to localhost). Then, hopefully, you'll get a more useful and detailed error message, instead of the blank page (which often is caused by some fatal error that have occurred during the initialization of the framework and its kernel)

*Update: Noticed now that you've tagged your question with 'windows', but that you don't mention which server you're trying to deploy to. I wrote the above with some *nix based server in mind, but hopefully some of it are applicable to Windows servers too (but there might be other common sources of error running under Windows that I'm not familliar with*

Comment: The server is linux based. I'll try the things you said thank you! But I have one more thing I don't know how to do:
The "index" page must be web/app.php right? So how do I set this up?

Comment: This can be solved using an Apache rewrite rule, defined in a .htaccess file. There is a default one in the web/ directory of the Symfony2 standard edition - have a look at https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/web/.htaccess
Good luck!

Comment: Did you get this to work? If so, you might consider accepting the answer (mainly to remove the question from "unanswered questions") :-)